# Making a div appear on click of another div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to make a div appear on the click of another div. Essentially, I have a whole map, which I have divided up into 4 sections. When the user clicks on one section, it will bring up just that section. Each section contains other images and links, basically other divs, within itself.

I am aware of CSS's { display:none } property, but I'm wondering if this only makes it invisible (links are still clickable though you can't see them) or does this make the div entirely disappear?

Comment: It makes the element completely disappear. `visibility: hidden;` would make the element transparent but still clickable.

Comment: As described [here](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_display_visibility.asp), setting the visibility to 'hidden' just hides the element, but it will still take up space in the DOM. Setting display to 'none' will completely hide the element and not take up any space, like it's not even there.

Comment: We can provide better feedback if we have some of your code to look at. The `display: none` part is easy for us to answer but we need some of your attempted work for the first part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly what you're asking for (the title/first paragraph and the second paragraph seem to be asking different questions), but here is the answer to the second paragraph:

`display: none;` removes an element from the layout, but not the DOM. You can't click it, but you can still interact with it via JavaScript. `visibility: hidden;` makes an element entirely transparent, but maintains its placement in the layout. Again, you cannot click it, but you can still interact with it via JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have a map image and then when you hover on the sections of the map something changes on the map like loading in another div over that section you can use zindex and hover in css.

If you want it to do something when you click the section of the map then its some jquery added into the mix

so your map will be a background image.
your sections will change when you hover over them: simple css:hover will do that with some z-index tricks.
Then you can do a simple onclick load this div on the position of the div you want to cover.

Is that what you want?